# Operator notation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, many-body

I'm starting out with many-body quantum theory, second quantization etc. by reading the book by Bruus and Flensberg. In the first chapter they write;

"A given local one-particle operator $T_j$ ... takes the following form in the ket-representation for a single particle system:

$T_j = \sum_{\nu_a, \nu_b} T_{v_b, v_a} | \psi_{\nu_b} (\textbf{r}_j) \rangle \langle \psi_{\nu_a} (\textbf{r}_j) |$",

where $\nu$ are given quantum numbers. Two things about this notation confuses me:

1. If it is a single particle state, why are we counting  two wavefunctions with different quantum numbers? It this just a formality?

   2. Why does the operator matrix include the wavefunctions to begin with? That is, why the outer product between the wavefunctions? If these are basis wave functions, don't we have a notation problem? I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: No, you're not making sense to me. That equation is just writing the operator as the sum of its matrix elements.

Comment: @L. Henry are you happy with the idea that an operator $O$ can be written in some basis of states $\lvert i\rangle$ as $O = \sum_{ij} \langle i \rvert O \lvert j\rangle \lvert i\rangle \langle j \rvert$? This is all that is happening here. If you are not completely comfortable with this then you should revise your elementary quantum theory before trying to tackle the many-body problem.

Comment: Indeed he's just writing the coefficients of the operator, anyway I would agree with you that the ket notation is an awful convention